# how to push objects into a list field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

If I had two documents like:

```
{'book': {'title': 'first'}, 'owner': {'name': 'Jim'}},
{'book': {'title': 'second'}, 'owner': {'name': 'Bob'}}
```

and I wanted to group the 'book' stuff into a separate list then the owners so it looks something like:

```
{
  'books': [{'book': {'title': 'second'}, {'book': {'title': 'first'}}],
  'owners': [{'owner': {'name': 'Jim'}}, {'owner': {'name': 'Bob'}}]
}
```

how would I organize the mongo pipeline to group these separately?

Comment: Something like `db.collectionname.aggregate([
    {"$group":{"_id":null, "books": { "$push": {"book":"$book" }}, "owners": { "$push": {"owner":"$owner" }} }},
]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do by running **aggregation** pipeline in your collection. `$group` it by `null`.

```
db.col_name.aggregate([ 
    {"$group":{"_id":null, 
        "books": { "$push": {"book":"$book" }}, 
        "owners": { "$push": {"owner":"$owner" }} 
    }},
 ]);
```